# Weird native datepicker display on Android

Tags: android, html, css, web, datepicker

We occasionally get bugs reported, where users say, datepicker looks weird and ist almost impossible to use (see Screenshot) after reloading a few times, the problem dissapears...

It's basicaly a HTML form with `<input type="date">`

Has anyone seen this before? As this is the native Android datepicker, CSS shouldn't interfere with it, right?

*(Screenshot is from Native Browser on Android 4.4.4, but the same problem was reported for other versions and other browsers as well)*

[image: Screenshot]